# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Validate Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, date

I have the following method to validate a date:

```
public static bool IsValidDate(object value)
{
    DateTime dateTime;

    var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value),
                                         "YYYY-MM-DD",
                                         CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                         DateTimeStyles.None,
                                         out dateTime);

    return (isValid);
}
```

The datepicker I'm using on my input field formats dates as `D MMM YYYY` so why does the following fail: `28 Oct 2017` using the above function?

What is the correct syntax/use of `DateTime.TryParseExact()` to correctly validate dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing the method as follows:

```
public static bool IsValidDate(object value)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value),
         "d MMM yyyy",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out dateTime);

    return (isValid);

}
```